# Returning to previous page loses the scroll position

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, scroll, ionic3, ionic4

I am working on the ionic 4 app.

I have a list like below:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of listItems">
    <button ion-item (click)="openListItem(item)">
    [...]
    </button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The `openListItem()` method in the `.ts` file of the list:

```
openListItem() {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/detailPage')
}
```

after going to the detail page and returning back to the list I lose the scroll position in the list.

I am using `ionViewDidEnter()` where I initially call the list on the list page...so every time I enter the page it calls the list.

Is there any way to keep the scroll position as it is?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the current scroll position and reapply when the route is triggered.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#properties

Get the Y offset and then

```
this.content.scrollToPoint(0, SAVED_Y_OFFSET);
```

Comment: I am using `ionViewDidEnter()` for the initial call of the list...so every time I enter the page it calls the list. and because of this the solution not working I guess. can you tell another way to overcome this?